# Debug.WriteLine doesn't work on different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

```
var timer = new Timer
{
    Enabled = true, 
    Interval = 500
};
Debug.WriteLine("new timer created");
timer.Elapsed += (s, e) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("hello from timer");
    // this doesn't get shown
    // in the output window
}
```

What do I need to do to be able to see my last `Debug.WriteLine()` in the output window above?

Comment: @ColeJohnson: No.  1) stdout is process-global.  2) That's not stdout.

Comment: Do you have other Debug.WriteLine messages that appear in the output window?

Comment: @Gusdor You mean except the first one?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you wrote a console mode app and its Main() method completed before the timer could tick, terminating the program.  Don't force my ball having to make guesses like this, its had a rough day already.

Comment: @HansPassant If you mean a console application - then no. It's a winforms app. The rest of the code in the ticks executes properly though, as I mentioned in the comments below. Sorry bout the lack of info.

Comment: Which `Timer` class are you using? [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @MikeBantegui System.Timers.Timer. I wrote it in the ittle but it got edited away by someone.

Comment: @Johan Please change your example to be a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that way we can re-create the issue you are having. Because right now, your code as-is, [works fine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5TmWK.png).

Answer (score 1):

You are actually not using separate threads, the `System.Timers` timer runs on the UI Message pump if it is available. If you have blocked the UI thread the timer will never run.

Check either that the UI thread is not blocked, [use `System.Threading.Timer` that does not use the UI thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx), or set [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to `null` so it will use a threadpool thread instead of the UI thread.

EDIT: Or like [Hans said in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598934/debug-writeline-doesnt-work-on-different-threads#comment30821889_20598934), you are running in the console and `Main()` is exiting before the timer has a chance to fire.

Comment: That's not it.  The event is named Elapsed, not Tick.

Comment: @HansPassant System.Timers has the same problem. Edited the post.